# How to get the speakableGroupName from the INSendMessageIntent in SiriKit?

Tags: ios, swift, messaging, siri, sirikit

I am creating a Siri Intent Extension, and I want to allow support for users to send group chat messages through Siri ([WhatsApp has this feature](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/whatsapp-for-iphone-2-18-80-update-siri-group-messages-download-1888925)). However, whenever I ask Siri to send a message to a group chat through my extension, the speakableGroupName attribute comes up null and the recipient gets handled as a person, not group name.

I have tried saying "Send a message using MyApp to a group titled Testing" etc, but no matter what phrases I include in the Siri call, the intent handler treats it as a recipient with name "Testing" instead of populating the speakableGroupName.

Ex. Printing `intent.speakableGroupName` gives me nil, but printing `intent.recipients` gives me a single recipient with `recipient.displayName = 'Testing'`.

Comment: Please add the code you've tried so that people responding won't be left to guess at the problem.

Comment: @Marcy I've added some code, but this is more of a general question than a debugging issue.